# How to add dynamic listener and get value of target

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a custom dropdown and would like to get the text content of the clicked element within.

Dropdown elements are created dynamically as are the event listeners but the listeners seem not to be working correctly.

Dropdown example:

[image: Dropdown example]

I can see the listeners on each div within the dev tools.

Event listener of child div:

[image: Event listener of child div]

The first div in the dropdown fills the input with it's value but the others do not.

```js
(function() {
  let departments = ['Accounting', 'Human Resources', 'IT', 'Warehouse'];
  let element = document.getElementById('dd-Department');
  departments.forEach(v => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
      element.parentNode.querySelector('input').value = v;
    });
    element.appendChild(div);
  });
})();
```

```css
.form-question {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 3rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
}

.form-question__title {
  color: #342357;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.input-container {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #333333;
  position: relative;
}

input[readonly] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-container input {
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  padding: .75rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-container:focus-within .dropdown {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.dropdown {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 12px #333333;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 2px);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .3s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #777777;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.dropdown div:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-question">
  <div class="form-question__title">
    <span>Department</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-question--dropdown input-container">
    <input type="text" name="Department" readonly="readonly"></input>
    <div id="dd-Department" class="dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also took a stab at event delegation, but could not get the text content of the clicked div. The target is the parent of the intended div, thus the text content was all child values combined.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('dd-Department');
element.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('dropdown')) {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input').value = e.target.textContent;
  }
}, true);
```

Event Delegation on click of child div:

[image: Event Delegation on click of child div]

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

Thank you @dawn for pointing out css as the problem.
I've worked around this by changing

`.input-container:focus-within .dropdown`

to

`.input-container.active .dropdown`

and adding the active class with javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.input-container').forEach(v => {
    v.onclick = () => v.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Issue now is that on click of anything other than the input-container the dropdown is still active.

The following works but feels like a hack.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.input-container').forEach(v => {
    v.addEventListener('focus', () => v.classList.add('active'), true);
    v.addEventListener('blur', () => setTimeout(() => v.classList.remove('active'), 75), true);
});
```

Are there more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is a problem with css,When you click on the div,The first thing that triggers is "transform: scaleY(0)" and the ".dropdown" has invisible,so Cannot trigger click event.

Don't use input:focus-within  to control the Visibilityof the drop-down box, because when you click the drop-down box, the input has lost focus.

Comment: @MJ12358 Maybe you can take a look at the bootstrap dropdown component.

Comment: @MJ12358 trigger the event at docuement or body,and determine if 'e.target' is includ the class,then control the list show or hide and assign a value to the 'input'.